# Django wsgi.py can't initialize the settings module: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'"

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi

My Django dev environment runs fine with the native server, but when I try to execute `wsgi.py`, either locally or on the production server, I get the extremely popular `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'` error.

The traceback suggests that the failure happens when `django/core/wsgi.py` attempts to execute `django.setup(set_prefix=False)` and that method needs to call `settings.[ANYTHING]`, in this case `configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)`.

Calling the `settings.LOGGING_CONFIG` variable tells `django.conf.settings` to initialize, but in this context it fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./config/wsgi.py", line 35, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\...\anaconda\envs\venvname\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "C:\...\anaconda\envs\venvname\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\...\anaconda\envs\venvname\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\...\anaconda\envs\venvname\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\...\anaconda\envs\venvname\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\...\anaconda\envs\venvname\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

The relevant pieces of my directory structure look like this:

```
parent-folder/
  config/
    __init.py__
    wsgi.py
    settings/
      __init.py__
      local.py
      production.py
  projectname/
```

My `wsgi.py` file looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent
sys.path.append(str(ROOT_DIR / "projectname"))

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.production")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I suspect this is something that I'll fix with a one-line change to a path or module reference somewhere, but nothing has worked so far. Any help is greatly appreciated.

*EDIT:*
The traceback shows that when `django/conf/__init__.py` executes `LazySettings.setup()`, the `settings_module` is successfully extracted from `os.environ.get(ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)`. So the problem is downstream of that, FWIW.

Comment: I suppose you just need to add the parent-folder to sys.path the same way as you do for folder projectname.

Answer (score 1):

In wsgi.py file, settings module is "config.settings.production", this means that settings directory should be a module. Therefore add an empty
`__init__.py`
file into the settings directory to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Mohammad - my setup includes that `__init__.py__` file but I neglected to include it in the "relevant pieces of my directory structure."

Answer (score 1):

Razenstein's comment is the correct answer: "you just need to add the parent-folder to sys.path the same way as you do for folder projectname." My path was missing the enclosing folder.

Comment: Im facing same issue, can @MW Frost post whole ans here? would be more helpful. also what could be projectname if using apps only in project.